# rdf file and blackberry touch screen devices

Tags: blackberry, rdf

from rdf file
http://www.blackberry.net/go/mobile/profiles/uaprof/9530/4.7.0.rdf

how do we know that device is a touch screen device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to infer it from this line:

```
 <prf:Keyboard>Virtual</prf:Keyboard>
```

But that would break down for devices such as the Torch which have both a touchscreen and physical keyboard (it's RDF has "Qwerty" for the Keyboard value).

The safest way to know is by using Java APIs, such as [Touchscreen.isSupported()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Touchscreen.html)

Comment: we have different build for blackberry touch screen devices. So from blackberry browser user will open our website and we will give him appropriate build.for that we are using http header profile:, in which rdf file url is there. at that point we cant user java apis.